# How to get name of GUID

Tags: visual-c++, directx

I am working with DirectX in C++. The function I call gives me a [GUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) structure as result. Now the directx header has GUID assigned like this:

```
DEFINE_GUID(D3D11_DECODER_PROFILE_MPEG2_MOCOMP,      0xe6a9f44b, 0x61b0, 0x4563,0x9e,0xa4,0x63,0xd2,0xa3,0xc6,0xfe,0x66);
```

My question is how do I get the *name* (D3D11_DECODER_PROFILE_MPEG2_MOCOMP in this case) from a GUID?

Comment: D3D11_DECODER_PROFILE_MPEG2_MOCOMP is not a name, it is merely a handy const identifier.  Helps you avoid having to write all those hex values in your code.  It is no different from #define M_PI 3.14.  You can go from M_PI to 3.14, you of course cannot go from 3.14 back to M_PI.  Google is usually pretty handy, just "0xe6a9f44b" is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such name, or human readable name for such a GUID that just defines a specific video profile.

You can create an array of struct with a string and the GUID to convert it. But remember that the name itself is just a define for the GUID. So it is just valid inside the C++ code.

```
struct S_GUID_DECODER {
  char* pName;
  const GUID *pGuid;
} 
aValues[] = 
{
...
  {" D3D11_DECODER_PROFILE_MPEG2_MOCOMP", &D3D11_DECODER_PROFILE_MPEG2_MOCOMP }, 
...
};
```

Now you can use a loop and can find "your" name.

PS: Your question isn't very clear if you mean GUIDs at all like interface GUIDs or class Ids, or if it is just this special identifier group for video profiles.

Comment: I meant only for this specific group of identifiers. Thanks for the idea with the struct

Answer (score 0):

`D3D11_DECODER_PROFILE_MPEG2_MOCOMP` is just alias for the GUID. You can choose any alias you like, but not simple one which are easy to repeat.

> Each coclass and interface has its guid, which is a 128-bit number. For easy use by the programmer, an easy-remember manifest constant is defined for each guid.
>   Source : http://progtutorials.tripod.com/COM.htm

Answer (score 0):

For those who are searching for similar results, the code snippet is from microsoft directshow samples, but changed to satisfy modern visual studio requirements (vs2019),

Main Code,

> Blockquote

```
#include <iostream>
#include <guiddef.h>
//#include <initguid.h> --- dont use it, use guiddef.h instead.
#include <cguid.h>

/*  Stuff for printing out our GUID names */
typedef struct {
    const char* szName;
    GUID    guid;
} GUID_STRING_ENTRY;

GUID_STRING_ENTRY g_GuidNames[] = {
#define OUR_GUID_ENTRY(name, l, w1, w2, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8)     { #name, { l, w1, w2, { b1, b2,  b3,  b4,  b5,  b6,  b7,  b8 } } },
        #include <myuuids.h>
};

class CGuidNameList {
public:
    const char* operator [] (const GUID& guid);
};

extern CGuidNameList GuidNames;

CGuidNameList GuidNames;
int g_cGuidNames = sizeof(g_GuidNames) / sizeof(g_GuidNames[0]);

const char* CGuidNameList::operator [] (const GUID& guid)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < g_cGuidNames; i++) {
        if (g_GuidNames[i].guid == guid) {
            return g_GuidNames[i].szName;
        }
    }
    if (guid == GUID_NULL) {
        return "GUID_NULL";
    }

    // !!! add something to print FOURCC guids?

    // shouldn't this print the hex CLSID?
    return "Unknown GUID Name";
}

int main() {
    // --- what is guid ----
    unsigned long  Data1 = 0xea36eb8e;
    const GUID MEDIASUBTYPE_None = { 0xe436eb8e, 0x524f, 0x11ce, 0x9f, 0x53, 0x00, 0x20, 0xaf, 0x0b, 0xa7, 0x70 };
    std::cout << MEDIASUBTYPE_None.Data1 << std::endl;

    // --- now get the guid names ----
    std::cout << GuidNames[MEDIASUBTYPE_None] << std::endl;
}
```

> Blockquote

The uuid.h is just a copy from windows SDK, for me it is installed in my computer, 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\uuids

The only change in this file is that

```
OUR_GUID_ENTRY(CLSID_SBE2FileScan,
0x3e458037, 0xca6, 0x41aa, 0xa5, 0x94, 0x2a, 0xa6, 0xc0, 0x2d, 0x70, 0x9b) ;
```

has been changed to (remove the last ";", which will give error signal)

```
OUR_GUID_ENTRY(CLSID_SBE2FileScan,
0x3e458037, 0xca6, 0x41aa, 0xa5, 0x94, 0x2a, 0xa6, 0xc0, 0x2d, 0x70, 0x9b)
```

Hope this helps.